# web crawling using apache Nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I am very new to apache-nutch/solr . I am trying to crawl websites using it. I tried goggling out about it but couldn't get required information. For example lets take a website and I need to get its title ,headers, content . how am I supposed to start it or any valid links would be appreciated .

Comment: This StOf answer might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033556/2849346

Answer (score 0):

Usually the wiki of the project is a [good starting point](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) (for version 1.x of Nutch). You didn't specify which version are you planning on using, but the 1.x is the recommended version at the moment (and my personal preference as well).

Comment: Not a particular one, the v1.12 is the actual stable on the 1.x branch so you're good to go. Also using the `trunk/master` isn't as dangerous as it seems :) you just need to build from source before using Nutch

Comment: can you maybe recommend a suitable solr version to go with that? I have recently encountered a similar problem, where the options in the tutorial for Nutch 1.X aren't even there anymore in the current Solr release...

Comment: To which options are you talking about? the `schema.xml` file should work with current versions, although in recent releases the approach to start solr and the folder structure have changed, so perhaps updating the tutorial is a good idea, if you want to download the same version that is currently used to build the `indexer-solr` plugin download v5.5.0